# Static and multiple functions with same name in different headers

Tags: c

I have two header files which define two functions with same name and different parameters. I know c doesn't support function overloading, but I thought adding static to a function declaration would allow me to declare two functions with the same name with a caveat that I could only access them in a same source file. Anyway it is not working and I'm not sure why not? Is my understanding wrong?

Example:
file1.h has following function:

```
static bool do_something(int a);
```

file2.h has following function:

```
static bool do_something(char b);
```

main.cpp has both headers included:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
```

Example error:

```
file1.h:26:13: error: conflicting types for ‘do_something’
static bool do_something(int a);

file2.h:23:13: note: previous declaration of ‘do_something’ was here
 static bool do_something(char b);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How come `static` could make any difference? This is conflicting declaration.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to declare `static` functions in a header file.

Comment: The main reason is that C will use your function name to identify function to links when creating the executable file if the same name appears twice, the linker won't know which one is the good one. I don't think that `static` have any effect on name mangling in C and you have to obey ODR (one definition rule). In any case, your idea cannot works in your case since your `main.cpp` file include both files so there is 2 visible conflicting definition anyway from `main.cpp` point of view. If it were used from distinct source files, I am not sure if the linker would complain or pick one function.

Comment: Note that a filename ending `.cpp` normally indicates C++ code and not C code.  Do you have the right tag?  The right compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool do_something(int a);` is a *prototype*. It tells the compiler that function `do_something` requires a parameter of type `int` and returns a value of type `bool`.

When you call this function, the compiler can now check that you pass a correct argument and assign the return value to a variable of the correct type.

As C does not have function overloading, you will understand that there can only be one definition of the function in any one compilation unit. A compilation unit is a .c source file with all .h files included.

So the above description has no influence on linking whatsoever. If the function is not called, the prototype is not needed; if there is a prototype, it will not require the function to exist. And if the function is called, it may exist in any of the source files or libraries that are linked into the executable.

The keyword `static` for a function definition indicates that the function will only be visible to other functions in the compilation unit (and so must exist in source in the compilation unit). Inlcuding the `static` keyword in a .h file makes no sense as it will tell each source file in which the .h file is included that the function, if used, exists in that source file.

This description *does* have influence on the linking process, in the sense that if the function is used, it must be present in the current source file.

In your case, you must decide which of the two protoypes is correct and fix the .h file accordingly - or declare a second, different function, that takes the other parameter e.g. `do_something_else`.